# Morphisms as zigzags, composition as concatenation

Tags: category-theory

I am trying to find any references to the following construction that relates to zigzag categories (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/zigzag+category).

Let C be a category. Let Z(C) be the category with objects $|Z(C)| = |C|$ and morphisms $A \rightarrow B$ in Z(C) given by diagrams that look like: $\{ A \leftarrow A_1 \rightarrow A_2 \leftarrow \ldots \rightarrow B\}$ formed from morphisms in C.

More precisely, a morphism $f : A \rightarrow B$ in Z(C) is a *zigzag* from $A$ to $B$ defined by a sequence $t$ of size $n$ of morphisms in $C$ paired with their polarity $\{+, -\}$, where for $n>0$:

- $t_1 = (f_1 : A \rightarrow A_1, +)$ or $t_1 = (f_1 : A \leftarrow A_1, -)$ (for some $A_1$ and $f_1$ in C);
- $t_n = (f_n : A_{n-1} \rightarrow B, +)$ or $t_n = (f_n : A_{n-1} \leftarrow B, -)$ (for some $A_{n-1}$ and $f_n$ in C);
- for all $1 \leq i < n$ then $trg(t_i) = src(t_{i+1})$ where

  - $trg(g : A \rightarrow B, +) = B,$  $trg(g : A \leftarrow B, -) = B$
  - $src(f : A \rightarrow B, +) = A,$ $src(f : A \leftarrow B, -) = A$

Identity morphisms in Z(C) are then given by the empty zigzag of size $0$ and composition is defined by zigzag concatenation (essentially concatenating lists).

Does anyone know of such a construction already in the literature?

Comment: The localization of a category at all arrows, that is, the image of the category under the left adjoint of the inclusion of groupoids into categories, is a quotient of $Z(C)$ in which the composition of both polarities of a given morphism is glued to the identity. The construction you've given doesn't seem all that natural, since it gives no relations between arrows of different polarities...I believe you could also give it as the pushout of $C$ and $C^{op}$ along the inclusion of the objects, for what it's worth.

Comment: Thanks @KevinCarlson for the thoughts. You are right, I don't give any relation between arrows of different polarities: there is merely some zigzag diagram as a morphism. At the moment I'm not sure I need a relationship, but maybe it would help to give me something more standard. I will think about your suggestions.